# Why cant I use tag helpers to generate links to my Area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a Area route setup in my .net core 3.1 web app:

Startup.cs / Configure():

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(name: "secure-route", areaName: "Secure", pattern: "Secure/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=index}/{id?}");
            });
```

The routing for this works fine, all pages under "/secure" works fine. However, when I try to add links or post a form in any of the views, the give strange urls in the format of:

https://localhost:44370/MyController/Edit?area=secure

This should be: https://localhost:44370/Secure/MyController/Edit

Any ideas whats wrong?

I have tried all matter of tag-helpers, but the problem seems to be with the routing itself.
None of these work:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Edit" asp-area="secure">
<form method="post" asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Edit">
<button asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="EditMyEntity">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Did you put `[Area("secure")]` on `MyController.cs`? And regrading to "None of these work", were they posting to wrong areas? Or were the URLs not generated incorrectly?

Comment: I have a SecureBaseController for each controller in the route, like this [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [Area("Secure")]
    public class BaseAdminController : Controller {} . 

All the methods above give the same URL format: https://localhost:44370/MyController/Edit?area=secure which is a 404

Comment: Do you have your default routing defined as well, following your `MapAreaControllerRoute()`?

Comment: @klasmack Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may missed addTagHelper for the area. So all the tagheler will not work well.

I suggest you could try to created a new _ViewImports.cshtml or move the default view folder's _ViewImports.cshtml into the application root path and add the taghelper codes.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Image:

[image]